# Rails devise reset :confirmed_at field when user email is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

When a user changes their email address, the new email is not confirmed. However devise doesn't update/reset the confirmed_at field.

I have tried:

```
before_update :updateEmailConfirmed, if: :email_changed?

def updateEmailConfirmed
  # check if there is an unconfirmed_email
  user = User.find(id)
  if !user.unconfirmed_email.nil?
    # set confirmed_at to nil
    self.update!(confirmed_at:nil)
  end
end
```

I understand the `:confirmed_at` field is for any confirmation, so it is working as expected. However I am using this field to track to see if the email has been verified.

Currently I have added an extra field to my User model called `:email_confirmed` of type **bool** and I set that to true/false depending on whether the current `:email` field has been verfiied.

My question is, is there anything built into the Devise modules that will allow me to do this without introducing any new columns to my User table and modifying my User class.

Update1.)

Here are the tags set for my User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :confirmable

  protected
  def confirmation_required?
    false
  end
end
```

This is what my User table looks like:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "email", default: "", null: false
  t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
  t.string "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.string "confirmation_token"
  t.datetime "confirmed_at"
  t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
  t.string "unconfirmed_email"
  t.boolean "verified", default: false
  t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", 
    unique: true
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: 
    "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end
```

Comment: You use `:confirmable`?

Comment: yes, I'll update the question to show my user table and user model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I could think of is Overriding the `Devise::Mailer` and the `Confirmation::Controller` provided by Devise.

I realised I can pass in a type parameter inside the confirmation_url that gets sent to the users email.

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})

    # determine if this request is to change the email
    # or verify the existing email
    if !record.unconfirmed_email.nil?
      type = "change_email"
    else
      type = "verify_email"
    end

    # get the link for the confirmation link and append 
    # the type paramater to the end
    confirmation_link = Rails.application
      .routes.url_helpers
      .user_confirmation_url(confirmation_token: token).to_s + "&type="+type.to_s
    .
    .
    .
    # send email with new confirmation link
  end
end
```

Then on the other end, when someone clicks on the confirmation links, I can distinguish the type of request by looking at the parameters:

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
    # confirm user 
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])

    if resource.errors.empty?

      # sign in user if they are not already signed in
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)

      # find out what kind of request this confirmation was for
      type = params[:type]
      if type == "verify_email"
        flash[:confirmed] = "Email successfully confirmed!"

        # update verified field which is used to keep track if the :email field has been verified
        current_user.update(verified:true)

      elsif type == "change_email"
        flash[:confirmed] = "Email successfully updated!"

        # update verified field which is used to keep track if the :email field has been verified
        current_user.update(verified:false)

        # send confirmation instructions for this new email so we can verify it
        current_user.send_confirmation_instructions
      end

      respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to root_path }
    else
      p resource.errors
      flash[:unconfirmed] = "Something went wrong trying to confirm your email? Contact contact@email.com"
      respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity){ redirect_to edit_user_registration_path }
    end
  end

  private
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource) # In case you want to sign in the user
    root_path
  end

end
```